# Preventing from duplicated code in get requests in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, timeout, watch

I have a watch on a filter button. When a user clicks on it calls to the watcher.
I need to send get request to the server. Get the response, save it and ask right away the next get request. One by one.

```
$scope.$watch('dataService.getValue()', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {

            var selectedValue = $scope.dataFilterService.getValue();
            $scope.httpService.getFilteredData(selectedValue).then(function (response) {
                var filteredData = response.data;
                $scope.httpService.getFilteredData2(selectedValue ).then(function (response) {
                    var filteredData2 = response.data;
                    $scope.httpService.getData3().then(function (response) {
                        var filteredData3 = response.data;
                        $scope.httpService.getData4().then(function (response) {
                            var filteredData4= response.data;
                            $scope.httpService.getData5().then(function (response) {
                                var filteredData5= response.data;

                                $scope.dataToMapService.init(filteredData, filteredData2 , filteredData3, filteredData4, filteredData5);


                            }, function (error) {
                                $scope.errorService.handleError(error);
                            });


                        }, function (error) {
                            that.errorService.handleError(error);
                        });
                    }, function (error) {
                        that.errorService.handleError(error);
                    });
                }, function (error) {
                    that.errorService.handleError(error);
                });

            }, function (error) {
                that.errorService.handleError(error);
            });

        }
    });
```

This code is working fine, however it is duplicated in two controllers.

In order to prevent from duplicated code i suggested to add new service and in it the code. However, it doesn't do the same as i expected. It is not waiting to the answer from the first request. 
What should i do to write it better and to prevent duplicated code?

Comment: You need them to go in chain or is it ok to send in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $q and $http calls array to make a single promise:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('getDataService', function ($q, $http, httpService) {

    var service = {
        getData: function () {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            var callChain = [];
            callChain.push(httpService.getFilteredData(selectedValue));
            callChain.push(httpService.getFilteredData2(selectedValue));
            callChain.push(httpService.getData());
            callChain.push(httpService.getData2());
            callChain.push(httpService.getData3());
            $q.all(callChain).then(
                function (results) {
                    console.log(results); //Array of results in the order of the send
                    defer.resolve(results);
                });
            return $q.promise;

        }
    }
    return service;
}).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'getDataService', function($scope, getDataService) {

    getDataService.getData().then(function(result) {
        console.log(results); //Array of results in the order of the send
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems great, however my code is failed on "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" when we go to the line - $q.all(callChain).then( and i don't understand why

Comment: did you copy-paste as is? @Mr.Question

Comment: Yes, and it did not work. I did a little modification and it works perfect! Thanks!